# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' ; the <py-config> need to fix in .html

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, mysql-python, mysql-connector

- the python script can execute fine by itself
  (logically I pip install all stuff I need)

```
import mysql.connector
import webbrowser
import time
import pymysql

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="196.168.16.144",
  user="root",
  password="password123", 
  database="cloud_db",  
  auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)
                
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_DESC  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = 'en_1-01'")                       
                                         
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

print(myresult)
```

---

**but run/execute in html faced   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'**

- error message

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 435, in eval_code
> .run(globals, locals)
> File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 304, in run
> coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
> File "exec", line 4, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

- run py script in html

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
      <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>

  <body>
    <b><p>this is the info from sql</p></b>
    <br>
  
    <py-config>
      [[fetch]]
      files = ["./get_sql_where.py"]

      packages = ["mysql"]
    </py-config>

    <py-script src="get_sql_where.py">
        import pymysql
        import get_sql_where.py
      
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Quesion: I already tried `<py-config>` but still facing ModuleNotFoundError, mysql .... how can I fix?

---

update:

I also tried to change the packages to ["mysql.connector"] but face the smae

```
<py-config>
  [[fetch]]
  files = ["./get_sql_where.py"]
  packages = ["mysql.connector"]
</py-config>
<py-script src="get_sql_where.py">
  import mysql.connector
  import get_sql_where.py
</py-script>
```

Comment: Make sure install `mysql` with `python -m pip install mysql-connector-python` and you may need to import that in the `<py-script src="get_sql_where.py">  import pymysql      import get_sql_where.py    </py-script>`  section

Comment: I did the `python -m pip install mysql-connector-python` , the terminal shows `
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in c:\users\chuan\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (8.0.32)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf<=3.20.3,>=3.11.0 in c:\users\chuan\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from mysql-connector-python) (3.20.1)` , and I also put `import mysql` into the script , the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you install `mysql` module like this?

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: yeah, I did pip install it, so that I ran the .py script itself can run. That run same script in html faced `ModuleNotFoundError`. Last time I faced, the `<py-config>` can solved it, this time no sure where it stock

Comment: @俠客行_dacodelearner I faced this once it, this may be because for different routes of modules which is being save. Try `pip uninstall mysql-connector-python` and then install it. See if the issue is solved or not!

Comment: I tried `pip uninstall mysql-connector-python` and `pip install mysql-connector-python` , the situation is still the same. Run the py script itself works, in html face ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: Instead of `import mysql.connector` use `from mysql import connector` and packages might be `["mysql"]`

Comment: @Talkhak1313 , but with that , the error will raise up`C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\custom_header_pra_1.12\test_showing_content_middle>python get_sql_where.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\custom_header_pra_1.12\test_showing_content_middle\get_sql_where.py", line 10, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
NameError: name 'mysql' is not defined. Did you mean: 'pymysql'?`

Comment: This error shows at least it's able to find `mysql` module. change `import mysql.connector` to `import connector from mysql` in the `get_sql_where.py` file

Comment: let me know if it works, I'll turn that into your answer to accept :)

Comment: @Talkhak1313 I think instead `import connector from mysql`, it would be `from mysql import connector`

Comment: @Talkhak1313 For one time install `pymysql` too as the error suggest...

Comment: @Apne is right, I wrote that the other way round :)